# Need Schengen visa in two month but don't have 3 month payslip

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, uk-residents

I am planning to apply for a Schengen visa to visit France in July from London (my nationality is Indian). I just started my new job and can only show a payslip for one month as I took a two-month break between my previous job and my new job. I there any way I can still get a Schengen visa?

Comment: You do have payslips for your previous jobs, don't you?

Comment: *Is there any way I can still get a Schengen visa* - are you asking if you can apply, or if your application will be approved?

Comment: I want to know whether my application will be approved if I apply now. My last payslip from my previous job is for January and my new job started in April